# Sort listbox entries by name

Tags: vbscript, hta

I've setup a VBScript hta to let my users choose a default printer. I'm currently trying to make it as clear as possible visually.

Our printers are listed as similar to:

```
4th floor
1st floor
Block 2
3rd floor
etc.
```

Is anyone aware of a change I could make to the code to sort the output of these by name? Many thanks

```
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Choose your default printer</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
    body { 
        font-family:Verdana; 
        font-size: 12px; 
        color: #49403B; 
        background: #FFFFFF; 
        text-align: center; 
        } 
</style> 

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    Sub Window_Onload
        window.resizeTo 500,550
        strComputer = "."

        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer")

        Set re = New RegExp
        re.Pattern = "^\\\\.*?\\"

        For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
            strPrinter = objPrinter.Name
            Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
            objOption.Text = re.Replace(strprinter, "")
            objOption.Value = strPrinter
            If objPrinter.Default Then objOption.Selected = True
            AvailablePrinters.Add(objOption)
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub SetDefault
        strPrinter = AvailablePrinters.Value
        Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
        WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter strPrinter
        Msgbox strprinter & " has been set as your default printer."
    End Sub
</SCRIPT>
Click a printer name to set it as your default<p>
<select size="20" name="AvailablePrinters" onChange="SetDefault"></select>
<p>
Close this window when done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), like this:

```
Set printerNames = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set printers     = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
    name = re.Replace(objPrinter.Name, "")
    printerNames.Add name
    printers.Add name, objPrinter
Next

printerNames.Sort

For Each name in printerNames
    Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
    objOption.Text = name
    objOption.Value = printers(name).Name
    If printers(name).Default Then objOption.Selected = True
    AvailablePrinters.Add(objOption)
Next
```

Comment: Would you please be able to let me know at which point this should be inserted in to the existing code? Many thanks

Comment: @ITadminguy The above code replaces the `For Each` loop in your HTA.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the printer names to an array and then use a simple bubble sort. The only tricky part is that you also obtain the default printer. So you'd have to save that while iterating your `Win32_Printer` collection.

```
' Create an array to hold the printer names...
ReDim a(colPrinters.count - 1)

' Add each printer name to the array. Also, save the name of the default printer.
Dim i, strDefault
For Each objPrinter In colPrinters
    a(i) = objPrinter.Name
    If objPrinter.Default Then strDefault = objPrinter.Name
    i = i + 1
Next

' Sort the array...
Sort a

For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    ' Create your <option>...
    If a(i) = strDefault Then objOption.Selected = True
Next

' Basic bubble sort...
Sub Sort(a)
    Dim i, j, temp
    For i = UBound(a) - 1 To 0 Step -1
        For j = 0 To i
            If a(j) > a(j + 1) Then
                temp = a(j + 1)
                a(j + 1) = a(j)
                a(j) = temp
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code fragment that reads from stdin, adds to a disconnected recordset, sorts recordset, reads and writesto stdout.

```
With rs
    .Fields.Append "SortKey", 201, 260 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Lne = Inp.readline
        SortKey = Mid(Lne, Arg(3), Arg(4) - Arg(3))
        .AddNew
        .Fields("SortKey").value = SortKey
        .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
        .UpDate
    Loop
    If Arg(2) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
    If Arg(2) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
    .Sort = SortColumn
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

or you can use the .net sorted array/collection.

```
Set sortthing = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
```

See SortedList Class in .NET framework docs.